# Stuck at reflection in C# for a method with a list of long as its only parameter

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this method in my `TeacherBusiness.cs` class:

```
public List<Teacher> GetList(List<long> ids)
```

I want to call it via reflection. This is what I do:

```
var ids = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3 }
var business = typeof(TeacherBusiness);
var getListMethod = business.GetMethod("GetList", new System.Type[] { typeof(List<long>) });
var entities = getListMethod.Invoke(business, new object[] { ids });
```

However, when I call it I get this error:

> Object does not match target type.

I'm stuck at this point.

If I change the invoking code to `getListMethod.Invoke(business, ids)` the code won't compile and I get this error:

> error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'object?[]?'

What should I do?

Comment: You should pass *instance*, not *type* as `business` into `getListMethod.Invoke(business`: `TeacherBusiness someBusiness = new TeacherBusiness();` and then `getListMethod.Invoke(someBusiness, ...);`

Answer (score 7):

You're calling invoking the method on an instance of `Type`... you should be invoking it on an instance of `TeacherBusiness`. (So it's the *first* argument to `Invoke` that's incorrect.)

It's unclear why you're calling it via reflection in the first place, but you need something like:

```cs
var ids = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3 }
var businessType = typeof(TeacherBusiness);
var businessInstance = new TeacherBusiness(); // Or however you get that...
var getListMethod = businessType.GetMethod("GetList", new[]{ typeof(List<long>) });
var entities = getListMethod.Invoke(businessInstance, new object[] { ids });
```